# Why does UMAC encrypt the output of universal hash function?

Tags: mac, universal-hash

UMAC uses a key to choose a random hash function from a family of universal hash functions. The value of the hash function is always encrypted using yet another key, and the resulting ciphertext becomes the MAC code.

- What would go wrong if I skipped the encryption step?
- In case I **have to** skip the encryption step (but I can choose different universal hash function than UHASH), what properties would be required from the universal hash function to make the scheme secure?

Comment: In case you "**have to** skip the encryption step", the property which "would be required from the $\hspace{.44 in}$ universal hash function to make the scheme secure" is that the universal hash family be a secure MAC. $\hspace{.29 in}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would go wrong if I skipped the encryption step?

It's be easy for someone getting some message/UHASH pairs get enough information about the key to produce further message/UHASH pairs himself.  If he receives enough pairs (and it wouldn't take that much), he can fully recover the entire key (and then generate a UHASH for any message of his choosing).

To take a simple example, suppose the attacker receives the UHASH for two messages that differ in a single block.  If we call the data from the block that differs from one message $(A, B)$, the UHASH for the first message is $(k_1 - A) \cdot (k_2 - B) + M$ (where $M$ is the contribution from the rest of the message, and $k_1, k_2$ is the UHASH keying data for that block); if the data from the second message is $(C, D)$, then the UHASH for that second message is $(k_1 - C) \cdot (k_2 - D) + M$ (with $M$ being the same, as we assumed that the rest of the message is the same).

If we substract these two, the attacker can recover the value $(k_1 - A) \cdot (k_2 - B) - (k_1 - C) \cdot (k_2 - D) = AB+CD - (B+D)k_1 - (A+C)k_2$

He has a nontrivial probability of being able to recover $k_1, k_2$ just from this; if not, a third message that differs in only this block will make the recovery unique.

This observation is not difficult to extend to sets of messages that differ in multiple blocks.

> In case I have to skip the encryption step, what properties would be required from the universal hash function to make the scheme secure?

I can't add much to what Ricky Demer has already said; if you need a function that can be used as a MAC, it needs to have the security properties of a MAC

Comment: Just to supplement this answer, the $(k_1 - A) \cdot (k_2 - B) + M$ seems to come from the [NH hash family construction](http://fastcrypto.org/umac/umac_thesis.pdf) (page 19).